# How does the GMail app implement its selection summary in ActionBar?

Tags: android

When an email is selected for deletion in the GMail app, the ActionBar looks like so:

[image]

There is a check mark and selection count displayed, with a subtle entry and exit animation. It appears it's an overlay that's on top of the ActionBar or replaces it.

Since I don't know the name of this widget I have trouble finding info about it.

- Is it part of the API? Google Calendar has a similar overlay when creating an event, which makes me think it's possibly part of the API.
- If it is, what is it called?
- How is the ActionBar updated with the row selection count? (No need for code, just a brief explanation would be helpful on how to write content to the the ActionBar overlay shown in the image).

Comment: I believe it's Contextual ActionBar.

Comment: @RobGThai Thanks. You're right, see my answer below. In the Developer Pages they refer to it as Contextual ActionBar, Contextual ActionMode or just ActionMode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing a partial answer to my own question. Hope this helps someone.

It's part of the API since Level 11 and is called contextual [ActionMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html). The idea is to enable the user to perform some specific action without leaving the `Activity` or `Fragment`. The references docs describe it like so:

> Represents a contextual mode of the user interface. Action modes can be used to provide alternative interaction modes and replace parts of the normal UI until finished.

Android Developers have a [section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) on it, saying:

> The contextual action mode is available on Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher and is the preferred technique for displaying contextual actions when available

There is a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#tutorial_contextualmenu) by Lars Vogella with a screen shot showing it's the same kind of overlay as seen in the GMail app.

Here is a screen shot from Android Developers (screen shot is licensed under Apache 2.0):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First it is not the part of the API and to update the count in action bar just add a listener for check box upon check increment the count and upon un-check decrements  the count so simple :)

**Update**

alternately you can use this custom [action bar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm familiar with ++/-- of variables. My question was more about how the count is updated in what appears to be an animated overlay to the ActionBar, and how that overlay is achieved. Is it a custom ActionBar layout - but how come it looks like it's on top / replaces the ActionBar? For a complete reference see the GMail app.